# Use parent function parameter in a closure

Tags: php, closures, laravel, laravel-4

I'm trying to use a parameter that is passed through to resource controller action in Laravel 4 in a closure that is filtering a model collection, however I get the error below:

`Undefined variable: slug`

How can I pass through the `$slug` parameter from the route through to the collection filter closure?

```
public function show($slug)
{
    return Auth::user()->sessions->filter(function($session)
    {
        return $session->slug == $slug;
    });
}
```

All I am trying to achieve is to return the session of the user that matches the given slug. I've tried something like this to no avail:

```
Auth::user()->sessions->whereSlug($slug);
```

Comment: Have you tried passing it as a second parameter?

Comment: I did, and that resulted in `Missing argument 2 for SessionsController::{closure}()`. nickb's solution is the correct one.

Comment: Agreed. I am not familiar with Larvel. Sounds like it expects a certain signature for its closure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try a `use()` clause:

```
return Auth::user()->sessions->filter(function($session) use( $slug)
{
    return $session->slug == $slug;
});
```

Comment: Perfect, was not aware of `use`. Learnt something new, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The second attempt I used (instead of a filter) did not work because I was using an Eloquent method on what is essentially a Fluent (query builder) interface. It could be fixed as such:

```
Auth::user()->sessions->where('slug', '=', $slug)->first();
```

Posting this as it may be helpful to others.